# Curl in bash code - produces wrong status

Tags: bash, curl

This code seems to ouput a http status of 000 - which seems to indicate something didn't connect properly but when I do this curl outside of the bash script it works fine and produces a 200 so something with this code is off... any guidance?

```
#!/bin/bash

URLs=$(cat test.txt | grep Url | awk -F\  ' { print $2 } ')
# printf "Preparing to check $URLs \n"
for line in $URLs
    do curl  -L -s -w "%{http_code} %{url_effective}\\n" $line
done
```

Comment: What is the value of $line when that happens?

Comment: I dunno - how do I find out? suppose I can echo line head of the command?

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)